# Close specific bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, angular8

I use multiple modals in Angular 8/Typescript.
1st modal opens and displays information.
2nd modal opens and allows you to do some work.
then shows another confirmation modal (yes/no) with @Output that I subscribe to.

If the answer comes back yes I want to close the confirmation modal which is pretty easy but I have not been able to close the 2nd modal at the same time.

modal 1 opens 2nd modal...

```
config = {
   animated: true,
   keyboard: true,
   backdrop: true,
   ignoreBackdropClick: true,
   class: 'modal-dialog-centered'
};
openSecondModal() {    
this.bsModalRef = this.myBsModalService.show(SecondModalComponent, this.config);
}
```

3rd confirmation modal...

```
  const initialState = {
     message: 'Yes/No modal',
     title: '3rd Modal',
     iconType: 'success',
     modalSize: 'modalSmall'
     };
          this.thirdModalRef = this.modalService.show(FeedbackModalComponent, { initialState });
          this.thirdModalRef.content.buttonClick.subscribe((feedbackData) => {
            if (feedbackData != null) {
             ****************************************
               CLOSE SECOND MODAL HERE
             ****************************************
            }
          });
```

I've tried several things and nothing seems to hide the 2nd modal...it just seems to make it hang so I can't close it at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some names clashing, this fixed the issue...

```
const initialState = {
 message: 'Yes/No modal',
 title: '3rd Modal',
 iconType: 'success',
 modalSize: 'modalSmall'
 };
      this.thirdModalRef = this.modalService.show(FeedbackModalComponent, { 
      initialState });
      this.thirdModalRef.content.buttonClick.subscribe((feedbackData) => {
        if (feedbackData != null) {
              
              this.thirdModalRef.hide();
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add *id* to close modal button in **html**.

```
<button id="closeModal1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Then use this code in **ts** side.

```
document.getElementById("closeModal1").click();
```

When it fire modal is closed. If you want to hide the close button use this in html instead of first one.

```
 <button id="closeModal1" [hidden]="true" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

You can close any modal using different *id*.